# Storing records in an array wtih mips

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, record

I am supposed to store an array of 10 records with each record having a name (40 char), age, and salary.

I've made a loop to store the user input and another loop to print it out but my output shows something different. I'm not sure if I am correctly storing the records? advice please.

this is my output. for testing i just had 3 records.

```
 There are 10 records.
 first employee
 23
 20
 second employee
 34
 20
 third employee
 25
 23  
 third employee
 23
 20

 23
 20

 23
 20

-- program is finished running --
```

my code is something like this:

```
loop:
bgt $t0, $a2, print #counter = size go to print
#store name
li $v0, 40
li  $v0, 8
syscall

#reads and store the age
li $v0, 5
syscall
sb $v0, 40($a1)

#reads and stores the salary
li $v0, 5
syscall
sb $v0, 44($a1)
addi $t0, $t0, 1    #up counter
addiu $a1, $a1, 12  #shift to the next value? may be error here
b loop

print:
beqz $t0, end   #counter = 0; end
li $v0, 4
la $a1, Records
syscall     #print name
li $v0, 1
lb $t1, 40($a1)
move $a0, $t1
syscall     #print age
la $a0, newline
li $v0, 4
syscall     #newline        
li $v0, 1
lb $t1, 44($a1)
move $a0, $t1
syscall     #print salary
la $a0, newline
li $v0, 4
syscall

addi $t0, $t0, -1   #decrement
addiu $a1, $a1, 12
b print
```

Answer (score 0):

*Caveat:* You may want to post your entire program.

In your print loop, you are doing `la $a1,Record` [at each iteration]. This is resetting the base pointer [in `$a1`] to the beginning of your record array. This statement should be moved just above `loop:`

And, the increment of `$a1` at the bottom of the loops is too small. You need something that is at least the total size of the record. Here is what I *think* your record looks like:

```
offset  length  element
------  ------  ------------------
0       40      employee name
40      4       age
44      4       salary
48      -       TOTAL
```

So, you should use `addiu $a1,$a1,48`

And, when loading/storing `age` and `salary`, I think you want `lw` and `sw` respectively, instead of `lb` and `sb`

And, I believe your loop to store records has some more issues.

In particular, the syscall to read in the name is incorrect. You'll need to setup:

```
    # assuming a0 points to the name field
    li      $v0,8                   # syscall for gets (read string)
    li      $a1,40                  # string length
    syscall
```

So, above the start of the read loop, you need `la $a0,Record` and the other usages of `$a1` need to be `$a0` instead